# how is pandas / numpy NaN represented in binary format

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I tried to write a Pandas dataframe in a binary file. The dataframe contains quite a few `NaN` values in many of its columns (assume the dataframe only has `float64` columns. This was the code snippet to write it:

```
import pandas as pd
...
bfile = open(r'...\myfilename.bin','wb')
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
   bfile.write(struct.pack('%id' % df.shape[0], *df[:,i]))
bfile.close()
```

This was the code snippet to read it back (read it one-column at a time and doing a `concat` operation):

```
bfile = open(r'...\myfilename.bin', 'rb') 
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
  if i == 0:
    df1=pd.DataFrame(list(struct.unpack('%id' % df.shape[0], bfile.read(8*df.shape[0])))
  else:
    df1=pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame(list(struct.unpack('%id' % df.shape[0], bfile.read(8*df.shape[0]))), axis=1)
bfile.close()
```

The two processes above handled `NaN` very well. I checked both the original dataframe and the one reconstructed from the binary and there were no errors.

I intend to re-use these binary files into other programming languages (e.g. R, F#).

Would anyone know how is the Pandas `NaN` (or the Numpy `NaN`) gets written when we try to write it in binary format?

Does the `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack` handle the `NaN` ? Or, is any particular extreme value of `float64` used?

I'm using Python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE-754 representation is used, which defines how nan is defined and handled. See for example,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: great thanks. would you by any chance know if R's `readBin` or `writeBin` functions also use the same representation?

Comment: I would be very surprised if they didn't.  You'll still have ensure that you use a standard number of bits (e.g. 64) and standard endianness (i.e. what is the order of the 8 bytes that hold the 64 bit values--see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).